# Angular - How to get permissions in all component and to control functions

Tags: angular

I want to check CRUD permission of many entities

example:

```
permissions: {
 account: {read: true, create: false, update: false, delete: false},
 product: {read: true, create: true, update: true, delete: true},
 ...
}
```

In component A, I have 3 functions to execute based on product permissions, also effect buttons' show-up.

```
constructor(private _authS: AuthService) {}
get hasItemCreate(){ return this._authS.hasPermission('item', 'create')};
get hasItemUpdate(){ return this._authS.hasPermission('item', 'update')};
get hasItemDelete(){ return this._authS.hasPermission('item', 'delete')};

function create() { if(!this.hasItemCreate) return; ...} 
function update() { if(!this.hasItemUpdate) return; ...} 
function delete() { if(!this.hasItemDelete) return; ...}
```

How can I not to repeat same 'get functions' in every component?